# Why does the JSON returned from my Sinatra App give a syntax error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, sinatra

I'm developing a Sinatra app, which returns JSON, e.g.

```
  get '/clients' do

     # do stuff

     response = {
       "success" => "true",
       "msg" => "Clients successfully retrieved",
       "data" => {"clients" => @current_user.clients}
     }
     return response.to_json
  end
```

The returned JSON looks something like this:

```
{"success":"true","msg":"Clients successfully retrieved","data":{"clients":[{"client":{"created_at":"2013-03-31T22:50:18Z","email":"test@test.com","first_name":"Marge","gender":"F","hairdresser_id":2,"id":1,"surname":"Simpson","updated_at":"2013-03-31T22:50:18Z"}}]}}
```

When I copy and paste it into a JSON parser, it works fine.
http://json.parser.online.fr/

But when I fire up irb and try to use it, I get a bunch of errors:

```
1.9.3-p286 :001 > a = {"success":"true","msg":"Clients successfully retrieved","data":{"clients":[{"client":{"created_at":"2013-03-31T22:50:18Z","email":"test@test.com","first_name":"Marge","gender":"F","hairdresser_id":2,"id":1,"surname":"Simpson","updated_at":"2013-03-31T22:50:18Z"}}]}}
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
a = {"success":"true","msg":"Clients success...
           ^
(irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end
a = {"success":"true","msg":"Clients successfully r...
                  ^
  from /home/[me]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p286 :002 >
```

Anyone able to offer any insight? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

JSON doesn't constitute a valid Ruby [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html). It's a String that you need to parse with [JSON#parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse).

### Solution

Parse JSON as a String by enclosing it in single quotes or a Ruby quote literal. For example:

```
JSON.parse %q/{"success":"true","msg":"Clients successfully retrieved","data":{"clients":[{"client":{"created_at":"2013-03-31T22:50:18Z","email":"test@test.com","first_name":"Marge","gender":"F","hairdresser_id":2,"id":1,"surname":"Simpson","updated_at":"2013-03-31T22:50:18Z"}}]}}/
=> {"success"=>"true",
 "msg"=>"Clients successfully retrieved",
 "data"=>
  {"clients"=>
    [{"client"=>
       {"created_at"=>"2013-03-31T22:50:18Z",
        "email"=>"test@test.com",
        "first_name"=>"Marge",
        "gender"=>"F",
        "hairdresser_id"=>2,
        "id"=>1,
        "surname"=>"Simpson",
        "updated_at"=>"2013-03-31T22:50:18Z"}}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hash has key value pair denoted as { key : value } but ruby uses '=>' symbol to map key to a value.

Try replacing ':' to '=>' and it works fine.

```
eg) a = {"success" => "true"}
```

If you want to parse this Json to ruby has then use this snippet:

```
require 'json'
value = "{\"val\":\"test\",\"val1\":\"test1\",\"val2\":\"test2\"}"
puts JSON.parse(value) # => {"val"=>"test","val1"=>"test1","val2"=>"test2"}
```